# LDAP Connection to AD Very Slow, Timing Out

Tags: c#, active-directory, ldap

I am attempting to gather data from two separate sources: an AD Domain and an LDAP server.

Below is the code I am using:

```
            switch (dir)
            {
                case 0:
                    searchFilter = String.Format("(&(objectClass=user)(employeeID={0}))", lineData[34]);
                    attr = new string[] { "sn", "givenName", "l", "employeeid", "sAMAccountName" };
                    uid_ATTR = "sAMAccountName";
                    eid_ATTR = "EmployeeID";
                    dirName = "AD";
                    sr = new SearchRequest(adBaseDN, searchFilter, System.DirectoryServices.Protocols.SearchScope.Subtree, attr);
                    break;
                case 1:
                    searchFilter = String.Format("(employeeNumber={0})", lineData[34]);
                    attr = new string[] { "sn", "givenName", "uid", "l", "employeeNumber" };
                    uid_ATTR = "uid";
                    eid_ATTR = "employeeNumber";
                    dirName = "LDAP";
                    sr = new SearchRequest(ldapBaseDN, searchFilter, System.DirectoryServices.Protocols.SearchScope.Subtree, attr);
                    break;
                default:
                    WriteLog("Incorrect call to CompareDirectory(). Appropriate values are 0 or 1");
                    return;
            }

            try
            {
                if (dir == 0) { result = adConx.SendRequest(sr) as SearchResponse; }
                else { result = ldapConx.SendRequest(sr) as SearchResponse; }
                if (result != null)
                { .... etc.
```

The LDAP search is very fast, returning results in just a few milliseconds. The AD search, however, is quite slow, taking between 5 and 11 seconds to return a result.

At this point, I'm not sure if this is an issue with my filter, or an issue with AD. A quick Wireshark trace is showing the following, looks like a timeout:

[image: Wireshark trace]
I am open to any suggestions at all.

Thanks in advance!

**Edit:**
I decided to test this one step further by running the code directly on the Domain Controller using localhost:389 as the LDAP connection address. The code is still taking around 8-10 seconds to return a response. This may actually be an AD issue, and not a code issue.

Comment: Are you using Active Directory server 2008 and higher? If not, then please be aware that the `objectClass` attribute is **not** indexed -> a search query with a filter starting with condition for `objectClass` will be slow. Also, `objectclass=user` and `objectcategory=person` are mutually inclusive. Only difference is that with `objectCategory=person` you also include `contact` classes. You can safely omit one or another, depending on your needs.

Comment: Also, I'd recommend to use ldap filters where the most specific conditions are first, so if you have an actual employeeID you are looking for, put that condition as the first in the query: `(&(employeeID={0})(objectcategory=person)(objectClass=user))`

Comment: Thanks @ShadowWalker; we are using 2008 R2 so objectClass should be indexed. However, whether I have object class in the filter or not, doesn't make a difference. The query is still running at between 5 and 11 seconds. I'm starting to wonder if this might be a network or AD issue, especially because the search result response comes very quickly, but the conversation ends up timing out afterward.

Comment: I do not posses that deep understanding as to how and when the AD server responses so I cannot provide help in this matter. But perhaps it would be benefitial for you to attempt your query from a computer that is connected to the same local subnet as the AD server, if possible. However, I have strong suspicion this is network-related rather than ldap/AD-related... Or, perhaps the AD server is overloaded with search requests.

Comment: @ShadowWalker, I think you're probably right. I'm going to try running it directly on the DC using the loopback interface.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This ended up being related to a very poorly designed OU structure within Active Directory.

Comment: Improving stuff. Score doesn't matter for that